# Jquery read xml using each

Tags: jquery, xml

i have xml look like this:

```
<batch>
<status>true</status> 
<sub_batch>
<batchNO>TEST1</batchNO>
<batchExpiry>TEST1</batchExpiry>
<batchQty>51</batchQty>
</sub_batch>
<sub_batch>
<batchNO>TEST2</batchNO>
<batchExpiry>TEST2</batchExpiry>
<batchQty>52</batchQty>
</sub_batch>
<sub_batch>
<batchNO>TEST3</batchNO>
<batchExpiry>TEST3</batchExpiry>
<batchQty>53</batchQty>
</sub_batch> 
</batch>
```

my jquery look like this:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../inventory_ajax/di_get_batch.jsp?dinvid="+prd_di_inv_id,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(xml){             

                    $('sub_batch', xml).each(function(){
                    var value = $(this).attr('value');
                    var label = $(this).text();

                    });

                    },
                    error: function() {
                    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
                    }
                    });
```

how do i get it work by getting its value for each sub_batch and its content like batchNo/batchExpiry/batchQTY

thanks

Comment: The `sub_batch` elements don't have a `value` attribute. What are you expecting to get with that?

Comment: You can use `$('batchNO', this)` to access the `batchNo` element within the `sub_batch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 $('sub_batch',xml).each(function () {
     $(this).children().each(function () {
         alert($(this).prop('tagName') + ":" + $(this).text());
     })
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NZmt3/2/)

Comment: $(xml).find('sub_batch').each(function(){
                           
                            var label = $('batchNO', this).text();
                            console.log(label);
this work fine
                    
                            });

Comment: @David Glad my idea has helped you..!